# Como alterar a cor de um JMenuBar?

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

Existe alguma forma de alterar a cor de *background e foreground* da barra de menu do java?

Procurei em diversos foruns e tutoriais e não consegui encontrar uma forma de alterar a cor da barra de menu.

Segue exemplo:

```
public class menu extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public menu() {
    initComponents();
    jMenuBar2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    jMenuBar2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jMenuBar2 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem4 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem5 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem6 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu4 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem7 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem8 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem9 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem10 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem11 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem12 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu3.setText("File");

    jMenuItem1.setText("jMenuItem1");
    jMenu3.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenuItem2.setText("jMenuItem1");
    jMenu3.add(jMenuItem2);

    jMenuItem3.setText("jMenuItem1");
    jMenu3.add(jMenuItem3);

    jMenuItem4.setText("jMenuItem1");
    jMenu3.add(jMenuItem4);

    jMenuItem5.setText("jMenuItem1");
    jMenu3.add(jMenuItem5);

    jMenuItem6.setText("jMenuItem1");
    jMenu3.add(jMenuItem6);

    jMenuBar2.add(jMenu3);

    jMenu4.setText("Edit");

    jMenuItem7.setText("jMenuItem7");
    jMenu4.add(jMenuItem7);

    jMenuItem8.setText("jMenuItem7");
    jMenu4.add(jMenuItem8);

    jMenuItem9.setText("jMenuItem7");
    jMenu4.add(jMenuItem9);

    jMenuItem10.setText("jMenuItem7");
    jMenu4.add(jMenuItem10);

    jMenuItem11.setText("jMenuItem7");
    jMenu4.add(jMenuItem11);

    jMenuItem12.setText("jMenuItem7");
    jMenu4.add(jMenuItem12);

    jMenuBar2.add(jMenu4);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar2);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 548, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 376, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new menu().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar2;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem10;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem11;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem12;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem4;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem5;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem6;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem7;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem8;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem9;
// End of variables declaration 


}
```

Comment: Depende, qual [LAF](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look_and_Feel) você está usando?

Comment: Estou utilizando a LAF nimbus.

Comment: Só alterar a cor da barra, não vai mexer nas cores dos itens com e sem seleção não ne?

Comment: Gostaria de colocar-la preta, com o foreground branco os itens da mesma forma, quando aplico os métodos não acontece nada, gostaria de destacar a seleção do item e do menu selecionado..

Comment: E quando os itens forem selecionados?

Comment: Gostaria de alterar para que fosse compatível com a cor da barra tipo um cinza no item selecionado com a cor da fonte em preto, não sei se é possivel..

Comment: Fundo preto com seleção cinza?

Comment: Sim, é por ai mesmo...

Comment: Já vou te adiantando, isso dá muito trabalho de fazer, e você vai perder parte da aparência do nimbus, como os gradientes. A forma menos trabalhosa de fazer isso é removendo a aparencia do nimbus e alterando a opacidade, mas vai ficar parecido aqueles menus do windows 98. Isso faz alguma diferença pra você?

Comment: Precisaria de ver essa menos trabalhosa pra ter uma ideia.. as veses não compensa..

Comment: Espera ai que vou postar um exemplo usando seu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma mais simples que encontrei é sobrescrever o método `paint()` da classe [**`BasicMenuBar`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicMenuBarUI.html), e configurando-a para sua `JMenuBar`. Para alterar a cor desejada, edite a linha  `g.setColor(Color.black);`.

Isto poderia também ser feito para cada um dos menus e menuItens, mas para evitar excesso de repetição, fiz um método chamado `customizeMenuBar()`, que recebe um tipo `JMenuBar` e altera a barra de menu, os menus nela contidos e seus sub-itens, conforme as cores passadas pra outro método chamado `changeComponentColors()`.

```
private void customizeMenuBar(JMenuBar menuBar) {

    menuBar.setUI(new BasicMenuBarUI() {

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
        }

    });

    MenuElement[] menus = menuBar.getSubElements();

    for (MenuElement menuElement : menus) {

        JMenu menu = (JMenu) menuElement.getComponent();
        changeComponentColors(menu);
        menu.setOpaque(true);

        MenuElement[] menuElements = menu.getSubElements();

        for (MenuElement popupMenuElement : menuElements) {

            JPopupMenu popupMenu = (JPopupMenu) popupMenuElement.getComponent();
            popupMenu.setBorder(null);

            MenuElement[] menuItens = popupMenuElement.getSubElements();

            for (MenuElement menuItemElement : menuItens) {

                JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem) menuItemElement.getComponent();
                changeComponentColors(menuItem);
                menuItem.setOpaque(true);

            }
        }
    }
}

private void changeComponentColors(Component comp) {
    comp.setBackground(Color.black);
    comp.setForeground(Color.white);
}
```

Basta adicionar os dois métodos na classe, e chamar o método `customizeMenuBar()` passando o seu `JMenuBar`, logo após a barra ter sido construída, no seu caso, após o `initComponents()`:

```
initComponents();
customizeMenuBar(jMenuBar2);
```

O resultado será parecido com este:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Deixo os links abaixo, para o caso de você querer uma personalização mais específica do LAF Nimbus, não é uma tarefa nada fácil, pois nem a própria oracle garante que os [valores defaults](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html) são realmente os descritos.

---

**Referências:**

- [How to change the Background color of JMenuBar and JToolBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752548/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-jmenubar-and-jtoolbar)
- [Nimbus  Defaults(Oracle)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html)
- [Change background and text color of JMenuBar and JMenu objects inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648030/change-background-and-text-color-of-jmenubar-and-jmenu-objects-inside-it)
- [How to change menu title color on mouse over (in java Swing)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485451/how-to-change-menu-title-color-on-mouse-over-in-java-swing)
- [Swing and Nimbus: Replace background of JPopupMenu (attached to JMenu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622138/swing-and-nimbus-replace-background-of-jpopupmenu-attached-to-jmenu)
- [Nimbus Look And Feel adjust colors of menubar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369783/nimbus-look-and-feel-adjust-colors-of-menubar)